# Query problem: there can be only one auto column

Tags: mysql, query

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with this table definition.
mysql version is 5.1.52-log

```
root@localhost spoolrdb> create table spoolqueue (
                             queue int,
                             idx bigint not null auto_increment,
                             status smallint,
                             querystring varchar(2048),
                             contenttype varchar(255),
                             characterencoding varchar(16),
                             body text,
                             primary key(queue,idx)
                             );
ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

Comment: I like this question (+1 for you) because it presents a MySQL gotcha which is unique to MyISAM. Asking about why is always much better than giving up and redesigning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will apparently work with MyISAM as storage engine, not InnoDB, if you can live with that.

Another way to get it to work is if you swap places of `queue` and `idx` in the primary key declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You can also give `idx` its own key if you prefer to have `queue` first in the PK.  Note the addition of the `index(idx)` line:

```
create temporary table spoolqueue (
    queue int,
    idx bigint not null auto_increment,
    status smallint,
    querystring varchar(2048),
    contenttype varchar(255),
    characterencoding varchar(16),
    body text,
    primary key(queue,idx),
    index(idx)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the queue field from the primary key.
You can index the queue column if you want

Comment: That kind of defeats the point of the table.

Comment: Do you realize that is what the asker is trying to avoid?